# How to send a picture as part of a multipart POST request - Java HtmlUnit

Tags: java, html, post, webrequest, htmlunit

I am trying to use Java to submit a captcha to decaptcher.com. Decaptcher doesn't really do a good job of explaining how to use their API's, so I am trying to figure out how to use an HTTP POST request to submit a captcha. Here is the example code I got from their website:

```
<form 
 method="post" 
 action="http://poster.decaptcher.com/" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="function"  value="picture2">
 <input type="text"   name="username"  value="client">
 <input type="text"   name="password"  value="qwerty">
 <input type="file"   name="pict">
 <input type="text"   name="pict_to"   value="0">
 <input type="text"   name="pict_type" value="0">
 <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

I am supposed to send a post request like that to the web server and get a string returned to me. Here is my attempt to implement that in Java.

```
public String getDecaptcherAnswer(String username, String password){
        try{
            URL decaptcherPostURL = new URL("http://poster.decaptcher.com/");
            WebRequestSettings request = new WebRequestSettings(decaptcherPostURL, HttpMethod.POST);
            request.setEncodingType(FormEncodingType.MULTIPART);
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new NameValuePair("function", "picture2"));
            params.add(new NameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new NameValuePair("password", password));

            //I added this block in 
            File file = new File("captcha.png");
            params.add(new KeyDataPair("pict", capFile, "png", "utf-8"));
            //----------------------

            params.add(new NameValuePair("pict_to", "0"));
            params.add(new NameValuePair("pict_type", "0"));
            request.setRequestParameters(params);
            request.setUrl(decaptcherPostURL);

            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);
            System.out.println(page.asText());
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(page.asXml());

            return page.asText();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
}
```

Am I supposed to set the value of pict to a File object instead of the String pointing to where the captcha is stored? (captcha.png is the name of the image I am trying to submit).

Answer (score 3):

There is a higher-level mechanism to send that file, you don't need to create `WebRequestSettings` and set its individual values.

You should host that static html somewhere and do something like the below.

If you still have an issue, please submit a bug report in HtmlUnit bug tracker.

BTW, HtmlUnit 2.8 is about to be released, give it a try.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://some_host/test.html");
HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);
form.getInputByName("username").setValueAttribute(username);
form.getInputByName("password").setValueAttribute(password);
form.getInputByName("pict_to").setValueAttribute("0");
form.getInputByName("pict_type").setValueAttribute("0");
form.getInputByName("pict").setValueAttribute("full_path_to_captcha_png");
form.<HtmlFileInput>getInputByName("pict").setContentType("image/png");//optional
HtmlPage page2 = form.getInputByValue("Send").click();
```

Comment: Yes, HtmlUnit is meant to take the headache from you :), please test with 2.8

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a [`NameValuePair`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/util/NameValuePair.html) for this but its subclass, [`KeyDataPair`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/util/KeyDataPair.html). This way you can specify a file to upload.

The following should work:

```
new KeyDataPair("pict", new File(fileName), "image/png", "utf-8");
```

The content type parameter is the [MIME](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2045.html) type of the file. Since you are uploading a PNG file, it should be `image/png`.

Comment: Would I declare the KeyValuePair as:

Comment: //Pretend I create a File object from "captcha.png" called file 
new KeyValuePair("pict", file, "png", "utf-8")

Are PNG files encoded with UTF-8?

Comment: I added an example that I think should work. I'm not sure about the utf-8 charset, maybe you should experiment a little with that.

Comment: For the charset, you can use htmlPage.getPageEncoding();

Comment: I made the necessary changes but now I am getting a timeout error returned from the site. I think this means that my request is working properly, since I wasn't getting anything back before, but I don't know why the request is timing out.

Comment: Also, @Ahmed, doesn't charset refer to the file encoding?

Comment: @Dylan, the current implementation of HtmlUnit sends charset as set by the page, if you believe otherwise please submit a bug report with minimal test case in HtmlUnit tracker

Comment: If you create an html page with a form as described in the documentation (http://decaptcher.com/client/) and in your question, does it work then? If it does, there's still a difference between your code and the expected form data. If it doesn't, there is something wrong with the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was trying to type:

```
File file = new File("captcha.png");
params.add(new KeyDataPair("pict", capFile, "png", "utf-8"));
```

Are PNG files encoded with UTF-8? Is that how I would specify the KeyDataPair for the file input? I think I am either specifying the wrong contentType or the wrong charSet, or both. Am I supposed to put them in all caps?

Comment: This shouldn't be a separate answer. This should be added in to your original question as an EDIT.